# Каким образом следует переводить термин "bounty"?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Каким образом следует переводить термин "bounty"?

- вознаграждение
- награда
- баунти

В контексте также встречаются выражения "Bounty Started", "Bounty Ended".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

- bounty = приз или вознаграждение, в зависимости от контекста
- bounty started = начало конкурса
- bounty ended = окончание конкурса (с награждением победителей)

(*Комментарий к ответу*: больше склонен к вашему варианту, потому что "премия", как мне кажется, больше о деньгах. Лучше использовать "награда" и "конкурс".)

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- Вариант 1.

  - bounty - премия
  - Start a bounty - Объявить премию
  - Bounty started - Объявлена премия
  - (manually) Award the bounty  Присудить премию / наградить премией
  - After the bounty ends - После того, как срок премии истек
- Вариант 2. Это слово не имеет прямого аналога в русском. Поверхностно, в нашем контексте, логичнее всего переводить "премиальные" или "вознаграждение".

  - bounty - премиальные/вознаграждение
  - Start a bounty - назначить/объявить премиальные/вознаграждение
  - Bounty started - завершить раздачу премиальных/вознаграждения
  - (manually) Award the bounty - вручить премию/вознаграждение
  - After the bounty ends - после окончания [срока] раздачи премиальных

Comment: На мой взгляд, "приз" вообще не вариант. "Вознаграждение" - вот этого достаточно.