# за вопрос полагается премия через ... времени

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

обратил внимание, что под заданным мною вопросом есть ссылка с текстом из заголовка.

насколько я понимаю, она несколько вводит в заблуждение — никакой премии за вопрос не полагается, а через два дня после публикации вопроса можно **назначить** премию.

вероятно, наблюдается не совсем верный перевод (к сожалению, не знаю, как именно звучит оригинал).

возможные варианты перевода предлагаю размещать в виде ответов.

---

**обновление**

кстати, ссылка ведёт на [этот раздел справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), где слово «премия» вообще не упоминается.

вопрос про перевод термина обсуждался [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/485/178576).

Comment: Чтобы облегчить поиск в дальнейшем, [ссылка на строки на Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265887?qt=%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: В транзифексе есть [_две_ похожие строки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265887?qt=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F): «`question eligible for bounty $when$`» и «`question eligible for bounty since $when$`». Нам нужно перевести _оба_ текста.

Comment: @VladD, если я правильно понимаю, вторая строка относится к уже начавшемуся конкурсу. тогда, вероятно. подойдёт что-то вроде: «конкурс объявлен … (дней/часов/минтут) назад».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Eligible значит «подходит», то есть мне кажется, что вся фраза означает «вопрос по внутренним правилам подходит для выставления на конкурс, начиная с ...». Но я, конечно, не уверен.

Comment: @VladD, наверно, лучше задать новый вопрос (сославшись на этот).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: [Так и сделал](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1280/10105).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявить конкурс можно будет через ... (дней/часов/минут).

Answer (score 0):

За вопрос можно будет назначить премию через ... (дней/часов/минут).

Answer (score 0):

Начать конкурс можно будет через ... (дней/часов/минут).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос будет доступен для конкурса через ... (дней/часов/минут).

Answer (score 0):

Назначение премии за вопрос доступно ещё ... (дней/часов/минут).