# Контекст строки о назначении премии

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, конкурс

Дорогие коллеги, я хотел бы выяснить, как правильно переводить сообщение о назначении премии (bounty) за вопрос.

У нас есть принятый вариант перевода английского оригинала `question eligible for bounty $when$`: `Объявить конкурс можно будет $when$` (обсуждение вопроса [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/930/10105)).

Но [среди английских строк в transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265887?qt=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8E) есть ещё одна: `question eligible for bounty since $when$`. Отличие от предыдущей строки — «since».

Знает ли кто-нибудь, в каком контексте и при каких условиях употребляется эта вторая строка? В обсуждении в комментариях к упомянутому вопросу, а также в главном чате мы так и не пришли к единому мнению. Зная точный контекст, мы сможем подобрать адекватный перевод.

Answer (score 2):

Я попробовал поискать данную строку на SO через google. Нашлось единственное точное соответствие. В этой [теме](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260294/5045688). Можно косвенно предположить, в каком случае она выводится.

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Почитаю тему по ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из [этого обсуждения](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10848/2977), можно предположить, что текст выдаётся на том месте, где была бы ссылка «начать конкурс» в случае, если

1. конкурс уже можно начинать, но
2. у текущего участника недостаточно прав для этого (например, репутация слишком низкая).